# JIRA: Generating per-user time report?

Tags: jira

Sorry if SO is not the best place, but I have time-tracking enabled in JIRA and want to be able to generate a time-report for each user over a given date range. The only time-tracking report option I have is very limited and doesn't do what I want, is it possible through standard functionality or a free plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this one:

https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/294

Comment: The only problem is that time sheet only reports on 2 months of activities

Comment: As it is now a commercial plugin you have good chances to convince the author to change that...

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check out [Tempo Plugin for JIRA timetracking](http://www.tempoplugin.com/). It offers timesheets, reports and gadgets on user, team, project, and customer levels.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pay a lot of money for a simple action like getting a summary of time per user.

I found this flow useful:

1. Create a filter that you like to measure (I measure time only by sub tasks)
2. Export it to excel
3. Copy and paste it into a google docs spreadsheet
4. In google docs you have an option to create a Pivot Table, so just create one that the rows are the assignees and the values are the time

You can also create a calculated column to get the time in hours (just divide it by 3600)

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not helpful because it doesn't show who worked on which issues.  One common report would be give me the total time spent by Edd on issues in a given query.  If the issues are not currently assigned to him, it won't show up for him.  If an issues was worked on before being sent to him, it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **[Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel) you can take advantage of all reporting features in Microsoft Excel**.

This plugin exports any sort of JIRA data (including issue fields and worklogs) to [custom Excel templates](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/customization). The templates can use filtering to the date range, and can display your report in an [Excel pivot table](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/pivot-tables). If you need further dimensions (like additional grouping by project, by component, by week, by month, etc.), these are super simple to add. You can also visualize the output in a pivot chart.

Tip: there is a default template included in the plugin, called *worklog-report.xlsx*, which can be used as is, or as starting point for further customization. It looks like this (there is a time-by-project pivot chart in the first worksheet, but I don't have a screenshot about that):

[image]

After the template is created, you can merge that with the most current JIRA data any time by a single click, or even [generate it and email it to you automatically](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/automation).

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer working on this paid add-on.*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with [Everhour](https://everhour.com/integrations/jira?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=k-stackoverflow-answers) add-on for JIRA. It allows receiving a comprehensive report for each user over a given date range. And you are absolutely free to build any other layout of your reports and add as many data columns as you need.

[Jira Sample Report - Everhour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTAz6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you can run the following powershell script to extract the data to CSV file.

### ## Instructions ##

1. Open Powershell ISE (It's installed to all windows 7 and later PCs)
2. Create a new PowerShell script (ctrl+n)
3. Paste the text from the following code block into the new file

---

```
##################################################################
# Variables
##################################################################

$username = "myname@asdf.com"
$password = Read-host "What's your Jira password?" -AsSecureString 
#$password = ""

$jiraDomain = "asdf.atlassian.net"
$projectKey = "ABC"
$startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact('2017-05-08', 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
$endDate = Get-Date
#Get-Date = today

$csvFileName =c:\temp\Worklog.csv

##################################################################
# Functions
##################################################################

function get-jiraData {
    param( [string]$restRequest)
    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri $restRequest
}

function get-issues {
    param( [string]$projectName)

    $uri = "https://${jiraDomain}/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=${projectName}"
    $issuesPage = get-jiraData -RestRequest $uri

    #write first batch of issues
    $issuesPage.issues
    #do next batches
    do  {
        $startAt = $issuesPage.maxResults + 1
        $uri = "https://${jiraDomain}/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=${projectName}&startAt=$startAt"
        $issuesPage = get-jiraData -RestRequest $uri

        #write next batch of issues
        $issuesPage.issues
    } while (($issuesPage.startAt + $issuesPage.maxResults) -lt $issuesPage.total)
}

filter convert-worklog {
        $worklog = New-Object System.Object
        $worklog | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name Person –Value $_.author.name
        $worklog | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name IssueKey –Value $key
        $startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.started.Substring(0,16), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm', $null)
        $worklog | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name DateLogged –Value $startDate
        $TimeMinutes = $_.timeSpentSeconds / 60
        $worklog | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name TimeSpent –Value $TimeMinutes
        $worklog | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name Comment –Value $_.comment

        $worklog
}

filter extract-worklogs {
    #$key = "WL-22"
    $key = $_.key

    $uri = "https://${jiraDomain}/rest/api/2/issue/${key}/worklog"

    $worklogsPage = get-jiraData -RestRequest $uri

    #write first batch of worklogs
    $worklogsPage.worklogs | convert-worklog

    #Check for another batch of worklogs
    do  {
        $startAt = $worklogsPage.maxResults + 1
        $uri = "https://${jiraDomain}/rest/api/2/issue/${key}/worklog?startAt=$startAt"
        $worklogsPage = get-jiraData -RestRequest $uri

        #write next batch of worklogs
        $worklogsPage.worklogs | convert-worklog

    } while (($worklogsPage.startAt + $worklogsPage.maxResults) -lt $worklogsPage.total)
}

##################################################################
# Execution
##################################################################


#Setup Authentication variable
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

#This grabs all the worklogs for a project, then filters them by 
$WorkLogs = get-issues -projectName $projectKey | extract-worklogs | ?{ $_.DateLogged -gt $startDate -and $_.DateLogged -lt $endDate } | sort DateLogged 

$WorkLogs | export-csv $csvFileName -NoTypeInformation
```

---

4. Modify the variables at the start of the file
5. Save as a powershell script somewhere on your PC
6. Run the script by double clicking it