# Jira work log report thru Powershell Scripting

Tags: powershell, jira

I was trying to collect jira worklogs and found one powershell script but it is erroring out with some error messages and tried different things to get to the issue but no luck.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:48 char:9
+         $startDate     = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.started.Substring( ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I tried to find where null is being passed and couldn't find it.

The code I was running is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43929401/10387680

Please let me know how i can run it successfully.

Comment: Did you set up any of the settings like `$jiraDomain` or username/password? from the code, it looks like the you will get this null reference if you can't access the API or get data from it.

Comment: i did supply values to those variables and also validated running the url in browser, I was able to see the data.any other thoughts?

Comment: From the error it looks like it doesn't get any worklogs in `extract-worklogs` and then would fail on the `$worklogsPage.worklogs | convert-worklog` portion. I would step through the code one line at a time to verify that you actually get data.

Comment: I took that part and ran the code but it still shows the same error. unable to figure out further.